# Do action on div in specific time periode (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to do an action on a div based on if it's an iPad and in a specific timestamp. The div should be clickable from 23:00 to 15:00 and then afterwards it shouldn't.

I have The current code:

```js
var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/ipad/);
var pDate = new Date();
var pHour = pDate.getHours();

if (agentID && (pHour >= 23) && (pHour < 15))  {
} else if (agentID && (pHour >= 15 && pHour < 22)) {
  $( ".menu-item-remove" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Frokost serveres kun mellem kl. 11:00 & 15:00");
  });
```

It just seems to break. It works well if I tell it to go from 23 to 15 and then make it start again at 16 to 22. Otherwise it breaks. It just has to do the alert and prevent clicking at all times except between 23 and 15 the next day. That's the only time it should be clickable!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can show the div only at a particular time using momentjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is this `(pHour >= 23) && (pHour < 15)`

The time(`pHour`) can not be above 23 and below 15 at the same time. so try with `((pHour >= 23) || (pHour < 15)`

**Demo**

```js
var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/ipad/);
var pDate = new Date();
pDate.setTime(pDate.getTime() + 18000000);
var pHour = pDate.getHours();
console.log(pHour)
if (!agentID && ((pHour >= 23) || (pHour < 15))) {
  $(".menu-item-remove").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("You can now order lunch");

  });


} else if (!agentID && (pHour >= 9 && pHour < 22)) {
  $(".menu-item-remove").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Frokost serveres kun mellem kl. 11:00 & 15:00");

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="menu-item-remove">Order lunch</div>
```

Comment: Hej Carsten (må næsten går ud fra du er dansk. Nu siger den pHour er over 9 og under 22. Men den skal bare kører fra 15 til 22 hvor der ikke er frokost og fra 23 til 15 med frokost. Kan jeg bare ændre 9 til 15 eller vil den konflikten da den if slutter præcis 15 også?

Comment: Yer I'm danish, but it's best to keep comments and other stuff in english, that way everyone can understand and read comments, questions or answers. `pHour >= 9 && pHour < 22` is just something I've changed, to test something. You should be able to change all 9, 22 to what every you like.

Comment: Right now, it shows the alert with lunch only available between 11 and 15, even though it's between 11 and 15. How come?